# How to I relate the signature algorithms of a Windows certificate, with the parameters for signing with SignTool?

Tags: powershell, signtool

We have a PowerShell script written years ago by someone who has moved on, to sign our ClickOnce deployments. This has worked well, until recently when the certificate expired. I'm tasked with updating the PowerShell script to incorporate the new signing certificate we recently purchased.

I put the new certificate into the Certificate store, per the instructions from the previous maintainer. I've made modifications to the PowerShell script, fixing other bugs as they've come along, but I'm at a place where I don't know how to relate the details of the certificate with the parameters for SignTool.exe. Looking at the properties of the certificate, from the Details view, I see the following relevant values:

- Signature algorithm: sha384RSA
- Signature hash algorithm: sha384
- Thumbprint algorithm: sha1

Looking at Microsoft's [SignTool documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe) for the `sign` command I see values used by the PowerShell such as `/td` and `/fd`, but I don't know which relates to the values displayed in the properties for the certificate. Also, I'm not certain that I need the thumbprint algorithm. According to the Microsoft page I referenced it should be used if working with multiple certificates, which the PowerShell script is not.

Here is what is currently in the PowerShell script for signing the ClickOnce app:

`Get-AuthenticodeSignature *.exe,*.dll | ? Status -eq NotSigned | % Path | %{&$signtool sign /tr $timestamp /td sha384 /fd sha384 $hash $_ }`

That now gives me an error of, "##[error]SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria."

Comment: I would simply start from the beginning and just use PowerShell cmdlets (and not outdated external commands as `SignTool`). This is a good bases (at least for me) to setup code signing for your enterprise environment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-1-of-2/

Comment: Thank you, @iRon, for your response. I'm a developer, who got stuck having to maintain this script. I say that because the terms used in the link you referenced, I don't know. I'll do my best, but this will take a while.

Comment: Follow up question, @iRon. I'm need to apply a purchased certificate to sign ClickOnce Windows application. The .EXE and .DLL within the ClickOnce deployment. The article you referenced talks about signing PowerShell scripts. I don't need to do that. Is that link still pertinent?